# Selecting data from specific user in mysql database to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select data from specific user in MySQL database to PHP using my session. Code I have is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = "$_SESSION['sess_user']" LIMIT 1";
```

I'm currently getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we're more than likely dealing with a string, you would need to add quotes to it and concatenate it with dots/periods.

I.e. `'".$_SESSION['sess_user']."'`

Just to be 100% certain, make sure you have started the session using `session_start();` at the top of every page using sessions.

Comment: Use a prepared statement

Answer (score 2):

just use ' instead of "

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '{$_SESSION['sess_user']}' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the . (DOT) symbol for adding variables to strings. Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = " . $_SESSION['sess_user'] . " LIMIT 1";
```

That's it.

Comment: Use a prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue

i just had to give my variable a name and use that

$sessUser = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

then use $sessUser in your sql statement

Comment: Use a prepared statement